# ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated doesn't work

Tags: selenium, automation

I have this code

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(".....")));
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".......")).click();
```

Sometimes I get exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a href="#" onclick="showRelatedPerson();return false;" class="button-alt button-icon">...</a> is not clickable at point (1233, 710). Other element would receive the click: <div id="jquery-msg-bg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
```

This is the element that I am trying to avoid by wait that I put. I am waiting until it becomes invisible, but sometimes even if it becomes invisible it still can receive the click and it is blocking the proper element to be clicked.

Comment: Can you share full exception log and exact selector you use?

Comment: I have made little update in question. I am avoiding to put any more data since it might contain some sensitive info.

Comment: What is the xpath/id of element you are trying to click? It might be the case that you want to click on <a> but the element you have fetched is a div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that once test reaches first line, the element that I wait to be invisible was not visible yet, but as test completes this line element becomes visible. So the solution was to add one more line at the beginning:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("jquery-msg-bg")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("jquery-msg-bg")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("declarationBusinessParticularsActivity.isMain")));
```

Comment: I have this same issue on many places so somewhere I use xpath and somewhere name but that was not important. The important this was to realize how this first unwanted element appears and disappears.

Comment: It might be worth exploring some other things to wait for here, as this could end up being a race condition. What if `#jquery-msg-bg` has already become visible, and invisible before you wait for it to become visible?

Comment: yeah this is valid question, but in reality test execution is much faster than application behavior, so I will not have this problem, I hope never. So, I will not worry about this (at least for now).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Selenium for 3 years. I was happy to try new version 4, yet it dissapoints me. I do not trust in ExpectedConditions as they do not work or doesn't provide the expected results. I do use them, but I often implement my own waits.

Try using this (I used this simple solution in many projects and it just works).

```
WebElement x = driver.findElement(locator);
while(x.isDisplayed())
    Thread.sleep(100);
```

Comment: I agree. Lots of tests that were working with Selenium 3.x is not working with 4.x, and expectedconditions seems to be completely broken. The same seems to be the case with all Browser.Wait() functionality. At least in angular applications. Never thought I'd say this, but Selenium forces me to switch to Cypress.