# Selenium waiting for loader disappears

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom

I'm trying to add method which will wait for an element to be invisible using explicit waits:

```
    public static void WaitForElementNotVisible(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds = 5)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(by));
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            throw new WebDriverTimeoutException("\n" +
                "**************************************\n" +
                "Below element should be not visible:\n" +
                "**************************************\n" +
                by.ToString() + " \n" +
                "Timeout after: " + timeoutInSeconds.ToString() + " seconds\n" +
                "______________________________________________________");
        }
    }
```

Tested page uses react, between page actions (switching between pages) there is loader icon which last between less then seconds up to 3/4 second depending on the action.

DOM of that loader looks like this:

```
<span>
   <div class="Loader__background" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: unset; z-index: 10;">
      <div class="Loader__foreground" style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; z-index: 20; color: white;">
         <div class="Loader__message" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <div class="sc-fzqBkg jCOtDD">
               <div class="sc-fzqPZZ kyyPPI"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</span>
```

When loader disappears there is an only empty span section:

No matter what locator I'm using:

```
public static void WaitForInnerLoaderDisappear(this IWebDriver driver, int timeoutInSeconds = 30)
{
    driver.WaitForElementNotVisible(By.XPath("//div[@class = 'Loader__background']"), timeoutInSeconds);
}
```

The wait does not work in a way it should be. Actually it waits and clicks on the page elements but it's done extremely slow. Loader is not "eye" visible" anymore but instead of moving forward it waits from 10 up to even 40 seconds between clicks. It seems that some kind of state is still visible. Where the problem may be?

Edit

As @Dazed suggested I've made a changes an right now I'm trying to check collection size.

```
  public static void WaitForElemNotDisplayed_byXPath(this IWebDriver driver, int timeoutInSeconds = 30)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            int loaderAmount = int.Parse(js.ExecuteScript($"return document.querySelectorAll(\"div[class*='Loader_background']\").length;").ToString());
            wait.Until(webDriver => loaderAmount == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
```

Is it correct to mix wait.Untill with Javascript executor? It runs faster but flakiness still appears so I suppose something is not correct.

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836656/expectedconditions-invisibilityofelementlocated-doesnt-work

Comment: added a timer version to my answer if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing I do is take a screenshot of the elements while it is loading and once it is gone. This helps me identify what is different. Many times it is just a style change.

You can try the below and pass in the xpath.

```
  WaitForElemNotDisplayed_byXPath("//div[@class='myEle']");

       public static void WaitForElemNotDisplayed_byXPath(string elementClass)
    {
        try
        {
            _wait.Until(webDriver => driver.FindElements(By.XPath(elementClass)).Count == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
```

you can also add a timer to it:

```
        public static void WaitForElementNoLongerDisplayed_byXPathTime(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new DriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 40));
            wait.Until(webDriver => Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(value)).Count == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I made it in a way you posted but result is that it works but it's extremely slow. I've made a bit of changes, instead of sing FindElements I've tried with JavaScript Executor which should be faster but I'm not sure if code is good. Can you take a look on my edited question?